# smeg refrigerator not cooling

Tags: refrigerator

My smeg refrigerator (SIL 566 H) is not cooling. The lower freezer is frozen and filling with ice, and the upper part is warm. After disonnecting the refrigerator for a few hours to let the ice melt, it starts working again for some days/weeks, and then gets warm again, while beeping and flashing a red !sr led.
This has been going on for some years, getting worse lately.
I've tried to find blockages or stuck fans, but couldn't find any. I also took down the inside panels and I can feel cool air flowing from the air tunnel, but it feels not cold enough.
Do I have to call a technician, or is there anything else I can try by myself?[image][image]

Comment: I wanted to buy a smeg, I really liked their retro design. Unfortunately, most reviews showed poor reliability.  Could be a bad evap fan?  Or your freezer is simply over stuffed. You probably need a technician on this one.

Comment: Would be nice to know what !sr means.  I couldn't find a product manual.

Comment: I would like to know that as well...

Comment: Just a guess, but !sr = "service required?" Our GE fridge behaves similarly if the kids leave the door ajar for too long. When that happens, I go into service mode and force a defrost cycle. It seems like the tunnel between the lower freezer and upper fridge ices up and blocks the air flow.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the defrost cycle is not working. Ice builds up on the evaporator and eventually blocks the air flow to the refer section. Defrost is set to occur usually once or twice a day. Most common failures are the defrost timer or the defrost heater. Sometimes though, it is the defrost termination sensor that is found strapped to the refrigerant return line. If you can locate the timer, check that the timer motor is turning . Some timers can be advanced with a flat blade screwdriver in order to start the defrost cycle.

The heater will be found embedded in the fins of the evaporator coil. (good luck trying to replace the heater) When the defrost is working you should be able to see some of the water from the melted ice. The water drains from the evaporator into a catch pan located under the unit where it evaporates. Squido

Comment: Good info here.  Welcome to the site, hope to see you around.